# Unable to send ALT + Insert using sendkeys in vba

Tags: vba, sendkeys

I would like to send ALT+Insert in VBA. Its not working please suggest.

```
SendKeys "%[INSERT]" // its work only insert.
```

Comment: Curly braces not square brackets: `"%{INSERT}"`

Comment: Hello @alex When i am trying to '      "%{INSERT}"     '  but it just type in the application window. please suggest.

Comment: In Office VBA that code sends alt+insert to the focused window.

Comment: Hello @Alex. Thanks for your quick response. I am working in excel vba. Its linked with IBM Mainframe. while I am trying to send enter key then its send easily but i am unable to send Alt + Insert. Please suggest any other. Can we send it through ASCII Key.

Answer (score 0):

Use Application.sendkeys

```
Sub Test1()
    Application.SendKeys ("%{INSERT}")
    DoEvents
End Sub
```